# jpa try to save and if it doesn't exist create one

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hello im trying to create a new user, if role doesn't exist, I want this to create one, but instead of that is says "the role doesn't exist". Is a @OneToMany relation each user have just one role.
I've tryed many things, it removes the register when I set `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` but it doesn't create one when setting `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`for example and saving.
I don't understand why can somebody explian me why?
Sorry for my english.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "username"
    }),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "email"
    })
 })
public class User {

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
public User(String name, String username, String email, String password, Role role) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;
}
public User() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

private String name;  
private String username;   
private String email; 
private String password;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Role role;
}





@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

public Role(Long id, RoleName name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NaturalId
@Column(length = 60)
private RoleName name;

public Role() {}

public Role(RoleName name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public RoleName getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(RoleName name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: relaciones.models.Role; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: relaciones.models.Role
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.save(Unknown Source)
    at relaciones.services.CrearUsuario.createUsuario(CrearUsuario.java:17)
    at relaciones.Relaciones.main(Relaciones.java:25)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: relaciones.models.Role
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:252)
    at 




 org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSav 
  eEventListener.java:182)
    at 






 org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(Abs 
    tractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(Def 
   aultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at 

















 org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:783)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: How does your `Role` entity look like? What is the exact exception? With stack trace please.

Answer (score 1):

Your relation between two entity is invalid probably,
one of probable solution could be as follow (works for me)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Size(min = 60, max = 60)
    @Column(name = "password", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Email
    @Size(min = 5, max = 254)
    @Column(length = 254, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_user_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Role> roles =  new HashSet<>();
//getters and setters
    }
```

and Role class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
//getters and setters
}
```

Further your role need to be in the database before the insert operation of user is performed

```
public User registerUser(UserDTO userDTO){
        User newUser = new User();
        String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
        newUser.setUsername(userDTO.getUsername().toLowerCase());
        newUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
        newUser.setName(userDTO.getName());

        newUser.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail().toLowerCase());       

        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        //USER OR ADMIN role should be in db
        roleRepository.findById("USER").ifPresent(roles::add);
        newUser.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(newUser);
}
```

Comment: yes but I dont want to insert role before, im using roles but imagin it's any other thing

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was setting id in the constuctor, I made one with only the role name and it made the insert`service.createUsuario(new User("nacho", "user", "m@gmail.com", "123456", new Role(RoleName.ROLE_J)));`
Thank you